# Facebook API access restricted: Platform Term 7.a - Provide required information - Wants Test FB user, but can't login with one

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

Has anyone tried to create a test FB user and tried to login with Facebook on their app / website?
Our Android Facebook app instance was recently restricted and Facebook's message requested we provide a Test FB user "FB test user has '@tFBnw.net' at the end of the email address" to test with, but when we try to create the FB user with permissions and login on the website / iOS app that's not yet restricted, we get the error message "User is not allowed to see the application.
The user is not allowed to see this application per the developer set configuration." although we had created the FB test user for that application.

Creating FB Test user using https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users
Logging into Android/iOS app or website. Android app is still set as restricted and iOS app / website get the error message "User is not allowed to see the application.
The user is not allowed to see this application per the developer set configuration." Expected to be able to login.